# How to change MikTex Console language from Chinese to English on Mac?

Tags: miktex, languages, mac

I have installed MiKTeX on Mac and it shows this way:

[image]

How to switch it to English?

Comment: well on windows the option to change the language is in the last entry of the menu (below "documentation").

Answer (score 0):

This is the location of an option

[image]